# spring-integration Exception on file schema

Tags: spring-integration

Hi I am new in spring integration framework  , I am just creating a xml reading application . but now i am facing an issue :
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file]

where I am having problem can any one suggest .

Answer (score 4):

The namespace handlers are automatically resolved from the JARs - you need to have the spring-integration-file jar on your classpath.

Comment: Using Gradle I get the same exception

Comment: You must also be missing the dependency for the spring-integration-file jar.

Comment: Nope, it was the dependency missing. I made the assumption starter had the file support.

Comment: Prior to 1.4, the integration boot starter used to pull in a handful of jars (including -file), but 1.4 only pulls in -core, -jmx and -java-dsl. I believe this was to avoid having surplus jars on the classpath not needed by many apps.